# Find all entire functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all entire functions $f$ such that $|f|=1$ whenever $|z|=1$.

My conjecture : $f=cz^m,|c|=1,m \geq  0$.

But I don't know how to prove it.

I will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function

$$g(z) = f(z) \cdot \overline{f(1/\overline{z})}$$

on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. $g$ is holomorphic, and since $1/\overline{z} = z$ for $\lvert z\rvert = 1$, we have $g(z) = \lvert f(z)\rvert^2 = 1$ for all $z$ on the unit circle. Hence $g \equiv 1$. That implies that $f$ has no zeros except possibly $0$. Let $m \geqslant 0$ be the order of the zero of $f$ in $0$. Then

$$h(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z^m}$$

is an entire zero-free function with $\lvert h(z)\rvert = 1$ on the unit circle. By the minimum principle, $h$ is constant (on the unit disk, by the identity theorem on all of $\mathbb{C}$). And that means $f(z) = c\cdot z^m$ with  $\lvert c\rvert = 1$.

Comment: I am impressed by this solution. Thank you! May I ask you some more details on the proof that $$g(z)=f(z)\overline{ f\left( \frac{1}{\overline{z}} \right) } $$ 
is holomorphic? I cannot understand why this is true.

Comment: The basis is the behaviour of holomorphic and antiholomorphic functions under composition. The composition of two holomorphic functions is holomorphic, the composition of a holomorphic and an antiholomorphic function is antiholomorphic, and the composition of two antiholomorphic functions is holomorphic. These relations are easily checked by differentiating, but are immediately clear when considering the "power series" expansions (antiholomorphic functions have expansions as "power series" in $\overline{z-z_0}$). So a composition of any number of holomorphic functions with an even number of

Comment: antiholomorphic functions is again holomorphic. Thus $\sigma \circ f \circ \iota\circ \sigma$ is holomorphic ($\sigma$ is complex conjugation, $\iota$ the inversion $w\mapsto 1/w$). Thus $g$ is the product of two holomorphic functions.

Comment: you said $g$ = 1 for all $z$ except for 0. this means $|f(z)| = 1$ except for 0. but $f(z)=c z^m$ is not.

Comment: @nicksohn No, $g \equiv 1$ doesn't mean $\lvert f(z)\rvert = 1$. Only for $z$ on the unit circle, because there we have $1/\overline{z} = z$, so **there** we have $g(e^{i\varphi}) = f(e^{i\varphi})\cdot\overline{f(e^{i\varphi})} = \lvert f(e^{i\varphi})\rvert^2$. That $g\equiv 1$ means that we have $f(1/\overline{z}) = 1/\overline{f(z)}$ for $z\neq 0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer You are right, I thought improperly. Thank you for fixing my bad.

Comment: Ok... But How can we consider the first equation..?

Comment: @nicksohn I'm not sure what your question is. Is the question why we consider $g$, or is it something else?

Comment: Yes, $g$. I can follow the solution (Very elegant) But How do I consider this idea at first?

Comment: @nicksohn Experience, mostly. One sees how powerful and useful the reflection principle is often enough, and after a while one starts recognising situations where one can use it.

Comment: Thanks alot. Very helpful comment! Have a nice day!